# YOLO Error: names: Using default 'data/names.list' Couldn't open file: data/names.list when implemented on CPU offline

Tags: object, detection, yolo

I have implemented custom object detector using YOLO for offline on CPU.

When I run this command on CPU:

!./darknet detector demo data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4-obj_final.weights -dont_show MVI_1615_VIS.avi -i 0 -out_filename results.avi

I get the following error:

GPU isn't used
OpenCV version: 3.2.0
names: Using default 'data/names.list'
Couldn't open file: data/names.list

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error recently. For me, it was a simple mistake in the obj.data file.
Instead of the correct version which is:
`names = obj.names`
I had:
`names - obj.names`
Hence why it couldnt find the obj.names file
Make sure there aren't any errors in the obj.data file. For more info, check out: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects